# Operator's, How to detect `MOUSEMOVE` inside of `LEFTMOUSE` event

Tags: python, game-engine, operator

I'd like to track mouse movement with the MOUSEMOVE event only while <kbd>LMB</kbd> is held down, but can't seem to get the two to play nicely together.

What I tried was:

```
if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
    if event.value == 'PRESS':
        *some initialization code*
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            *the rest of the code that relies on mouse movement data*
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `event.type` is `LEFTMOUSE`, how could it be `MOUSEMOVE` at the same time?
(exclude quantum mechanics)

The `modal()` method is called for every event, so you need to "remember" the left mouse state for the subsequent calls on `MOUSEMOVE` events:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move an object with the mouse, example"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    first_mouse_x = IntProperty()
    first_value = FloatProperty()

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            if self.lmb:
                delta = self.first_mouse_x - event.mouse_x
                context.object.location.x = self.first_value + delta * 0.01

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            # we could handle PRESS and RELEASE individually if necessary
            self.lmb = event.value == 'PRESS'

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            context.object.location.x = self.first_value
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        # variable to remember left mouse button state    
        self.lmb = False

        if context.object:
            self.first_mouse_x = event.mouse_x
            self.first_value = context.object.location.x

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "No active object, could not finish")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```